# Dynamically exiting the edit dialog box in jQGrid

Tags: jqgrid, edit, dialog

This is what I am trying to achieve:

Whenever a user selects a row for editing, I want to check the value of that row for a particular column. If the value that I am looking for is found then I want to display a message and close the edit dialog box. So far, This is what I have come up with:

```
    // Options for EDIT 

    {height:280,mtype: "POST",closeAfterEdit: true,reloadAfterSubmit:true, url:'gridedit.jsp',

        recreateForm: true, 

        //set some properties beofre the dialog box is seen by the user

       beforeShowForm: function(form) {

            /*$('#adate',form).attr('readonly','readonly');
            $('#account',form).attr('hidden','true');*/

            $('#adate',form).hide();
            $('#account',form).hide();
            var sel_id = $("#list").jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selrow');
            var value = $("#list").jqGrid('getCell', sel_id, 'mod');

            if(value=='n'){
                alert('NOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO!')
            }
        }
    }
```

after the alert, how do i close the edit dialog box ? right now the dialog box appears after the alert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

found the answer:

i just have to write

```
    form.close();
```

after the alert